# Distinguish parent and child folder in Google Drive - Flutter - GoogleAPI V3

Tags: flutter, directory, google-drive-api, subdirectory

I am struggling to find the right folder in Google Drive. I am using `import 'package:googleapis/drive/v3.dart'`

Folder Structure

```
--FolderA
 |
 |--FolderC  // Note this sub folder has the same name as one of the other folders
--FolderB
--FolderC
```

```
  var query = "mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' ";
  query += "and name='$folderName'"; // folderName = "FolderC"

....
...

  Future<List<File>> _runQuery(String query) async {
    DriveApi driveApi = DriveApi(await getHttpClient());    
    return (await driveApi.files.list(q: query)).files;
  }
```

...with the above code I can see the folders with their `id, name, etc.`. The problem is the `parents` for all the folders are `null`. Because of this I coudn't find out which 'FolderC' is which.

So, is there a way to find out a subfolder of a specific folder?

*Update 1:*

If I add parents in the query, I am getting an empty list (no folders at all)

```
var query = "mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' ";
query += "and name='$folderName' "; // folderName = "FolderC"
query += "and '${parentFolder.id}' in parents";
```

Comment: I think you may have missed a space between the query conditions. Change last line to this: `query += " and '${parentFolder.id}' in parents";`

Comment: Good observation. It was just a copy/paste error here (the actual query in the code does have a space). I updated above code, BTW.

Comment: If you use the query directly in Drive API list [request](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list), do you get the same empty result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, how about modifying the search query?

#### Modified search query:

```
"mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and name='$folderName' and '### folder ID of FolderA ###' in parents"
```

- At above search query, `FolderC` in the folder `FolderA` is retrieved.

#### Note:

- If you want to retrieve the information of the parent folder at the returned values from the API, please add `parents` in `fields` for request. Or you can also use `*` as the fields. In this case, all metadata can be retrieved.

#### References:

- [Files: list of Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list)
- [Search for Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/query-ref)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: Well, that would have worked if the "parents" were `not null` but what I am finding is the parents property/field of all the folders are null.

Comment: ... to be more specific when the query is `query = "mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' ";`, I am getting all the folders **however, all the parents are null**.

Comment: @Musa Biralo Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. From `is there a way to find out a subfolder of a specific folder?` in your question, I thought that you want to retrieve `FolderC` in `FolderA`. So I answered for this. But from your replying, I cannot understand what you want. Can I ask you about what you want at "Folder Structure" in your question? By this, I would like to modify it.

Comment: @Tenaike: No worries about the English, we all are leaning one way or the other. English is my second language as well. I am interested in finding "FolderC in FolderA".  As I mentioned, the core problem is "parents" being null for "FolderC"

Comment: @Musa Biralo Thank you for replying and your concern. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `"parents" being null for "FolderC"`. In this case, no values are returned? Or the values that have no parent folders are returned? Can you explain about the detail of it?

Comment: @Musa Biralo If `"files": []` in the response value is returned, please confirm that `###` of `'###' in parents"` is the folder ID of `FolderA` and `###` of `name='###'` is `FolderC` which is the folder name, again.

Comment: @Musa Biralo Although I cannot confirm the scopes in the script from your question, if you are using the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file`, please modify it to `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` as one of several scopes, and try it again. When the scope was modified, please remove the file including the refresh token and reauthorize again. By this, the modified scopes are reflected. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/about-auth)